# HTTP GET request in kotlin

Tags: web-services, kotlin, okhttp

I needed an example of an HTTP GET request in kotlin. I have a database and I already did the API to go fetch the information to the server.
As a final result I need to present the API json in the android layout inside a'editText '.
suggestions? I already have this code:

```
fun fetchJson(){
    val url = "http://localhost:8080/matematica3/naoAutomatica/get"
    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
    val client = OkHttpClient()

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            val body = response.body?.string()
            println(body)
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            println("Falhou")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an EditText member variable so that you can then access it in your Callback functions

eg.

```
var editText: EditText? = null
```

initialize this in the onCreate of your activity

```
editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
```

the set text in your call back like so

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
    override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
        println("${e?.message}")
    }

    override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
        val body = response?.body()?.string()
        println(body)

        editText?.text = "${body.toString()}" \\ or whatever else you wanna set on the edit text
    }
})
```

Comment: this mode i have a error in ´editText?.text = "${body.toString()}"´. You know why? @I_of_T

Comment: What does the stacktrace say?

Comment: For this way: ´editText?.setText(body)´ not gives error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [kohttp](https://github.com/rybalkinsd/kohttp) library. It is a Kotlin DSL HTTP client. It supports the features of square.okhttp and provides a clear DSL for them. KoHttp async calls are powered by coroutines.

```
val response: Deferred<Response> = "http://localhost:8080/matematica3/naoAutomatica/get".asyncHttpGet()
```

or DSL function for more complex requests

```
val response: Response = httpGet {
    host = "localhost"
    port = 8080
    path = "/matematica3/naoAutomatica/get"
}
```

You can find more details in [docs](https://github.com/rybalkinsd/kohttp)

As a result, your call with 'callbacks' will look like this

```
val response: Deferred<Response> = "http://localhost:8080/matematica3/naoAutomatica/get".asyncHttpGet()

try {
    response.await().use {
        println(it.asString())
    }
} catche (e: Exception) {
    println("${e?.message}")
}
```

To get it with Gradle use

```
compile 'io.github.rybalkinsd:kohttp:0.10.0'
```